# how can i program two dates using date picker and php?

Tags: php

i made a program for our company which is a travel agency. i have this problem about this inputing a flight details on my program especially on dates. im using date picker so that it will be easy for a user to input a particular dates.how can i set a program in viewing details between two selected dates. For example, from 13, jun.2011 until 18, jun 2011, i want to display all infos between those dates. i set my dates table in mysql as varchar..how can i program this one..can you help me ? can you give an examples of program regarding this issue?

Comment: `i set my dates table in mysql as varchar.` <= The Horror.

Comment: You should be storing your dates as Date or DateTime types, not varchar.  Beyond that it's not clear what your exact problem is.  Are you having trouble with the selection logic or the display of the information?

Answer (score 1):

More modern browsers (like Opera) allow you to use a datepicker with straight HTML - but that's only OK if you use an intranet and you can be confident of the browsers you need to support. The more common solution is to use javascript.

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/forms.html

If you like jQuery (and plenty do) - this library gives you a good datepicker solution.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display all the dates between two selected dates...

```
$thisTime = strtotime($selectedStartDate);
$endTime = strtotime($selectedEndDate);

while($thisTime < $endTime) {
    echo date('Y-m-d', $thisTime);
    $thisTime = strtotime('plus one day', $thisTime);
}
echo date('Y-m-d', $endTime);
```